# Texmaker Shortcuts not working on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10, qt5

Texmaker does not recognize shortcuts such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for Find or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for Open. This was a known problem in previous Ubuntu releases, but the common solution for those versions does not work for Ubuntu 16.10.

Attempted solution:

1. Running texmaker with the `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` disabled.

   ```
   env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= texmaker
   ```

Comment: Texmaker shortcuts now work in Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score -1):

Running

```
    sudo env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= texmaker
```

worked for me!

Comment: 1) You should use `gksudo` or `pkexec` to run graphical applications as super-user. 2) You shouldn't run applications as super-user that don't need super-user privileges as that is likely to create new permission issues; instead you should fix the existing permissions issues that prevent you from running the application as a regular user. -1